# I was trying to understand a code and I came across a variant of split() function which I can't understand. Please help me with this

Tags: python-3.x

> `filetype = file.split('.')[1]`

In the above line the I don't understand the use of [1]. The above line is a part of the following code:

```
for file in files:
        filetype = file.split('.')[1]
        if filetype not in file_type_variation_list:
            file_type_variation_list.append(filetype)
            new_folder_name = mypath + '/' + filetype + '_folder'
            filetype_folder_dict[str(filetype)] = str(new_folder_name)
            if os.path.isdir(new_folder_name) == True:
                continue
            else:
                os.mkdir(new_folder_name)
```

Comment: its taking the second element of a list.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Have you tried debugging it to check what it contains?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array Indexing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726618/array-indexing-in-python)

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your response. I am pretty knew to coding. Can you please elaborate the processing of debugging and also please share some resources I can refer to about debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are iterating through an array of strings each being a filename/path,

```
s = "MyFile.txt"
parts = s.split(".")
print(parts[0], parts[1])
# Outputs "MyFile, txt"
```

Essentially, this checks for the filetype. although files like

```
MyFile.txt.log
```

would result still in

```
txt
```

as `log` would be the 3rd item, so index 2 or in array terms, [2]